# WebRequest.Create improperly decodes url

Tags: c#, unicode, webrequest

I have a url like this: `http://localhost:8080/search.json?q=L%u00e6r`, which is the encoded search for Lær.

Unfortunately creating a WebRequest from this url using `WebRequest.Create(url)` produces the following url: `http://localhost:8080/search.json?q=L%25u00e6r`.

Notice that it incorrectly decodes `%u00e6`, and produces `%25u00e6r`. Is there a way to either convert this kind of unicode escaped value or get WebRequest.Create to properly handle it?

This should most likely be reported as a bug to the .net team. `WebRequest.Create()` cannot use the query string returned by `Request.QueryString.ToString()` if the query contains a §, æ, ø or å (or any other non-ascii character). Here is a small mvc action which can be used to test it. Call it with the query `Query?q=L%C3A6r`

```
public ActionResult Query()
{
    var query = Request.QueryString.ToString();
    var url = "http://localhost:8080?" + query;


    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/plain");
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

Unfortunately @animaonline's solution does not work with urls like `http://localhost:8080/search.json?q=Lek+%26+L%u00e6r`, which are decoded into `http://localhost:8080/search.json?q=Lek & Lær`, where `WebRequest.Create` gets confused about the `&`, and thinks it separates parameters, instead of being part of the parameter `q`.

Comment: If you pass it in without encoding, surely it would do the encoding for you?

Comment: I did not create the url, it was given to the application by a third party. Now I need to use the url against the same third party. It works in the browser, but not in C#

Comment: Ah okay! Try @anomeaonline's solution, it looks like a very good one to me!

Comment: Hey/Hei Marius, did my solution work out for you after all? (since you accepted it) ? :)

Comment: Have you sent a bug report yet? I still have the same problem in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution seems to be to split the query string into each separate component, decoding it and then reencoding it as UTF-8, before joining it all together again.

```
string FixQuery(string query){
  return String.Join("&",
    query.Split(new[] {'&'})
      .Select(
        p =>
          String.Join("=",
            p.Split(new[] {'='})
              .Select(
                q =>
                  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(
                    HttpUtility.UrlDecode(q),
                    Encoding.UTF8
                  )
              )
          )
      )
  );
}

//example usage

var url = "http://localhost:8080/search?"+FixQuery(query);
```

Comment: for people using .NET 3.5, this solution works but you have to wrap the second param to each string.join in parens and .ToArray() the whole thing.

Answer (score 5):

You have to decode your URL before executing Create

```
        var decodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode("http://localhost:8080/search.json?q=L%u00e6r");

        var req = WebRequest.Create(decodedUrl);
```

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect why, unfortunately, this method does not work